# IIS 10 HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found

Tags: vpn, iis, windows-server-2019

A few weeks ago our server hosting our IIS and everything failed. I didn't create the server but I am being tasked to work on getting everything back up and running. Previously backups weren't enabled so we lost a lot. I feel like I have everything back to where it was before but I am getting a 404 when I try to access this site from my VPN. When I click on browse localhost *.443 I can get the site to work.

Things I have tried:

- The site is started
- Bindings are what they were before
- I can access the site on my VM using the "Browse Localhost" link
- I checked network and local firewall rules and they are correct
- Downloaded "URL Rewrite" and my REGEX seems to be correct
- Anonymous Authentication is set to enabled
- Checked web.config file and from what I can tell everything is good
  there.

I have followed every link in Google that I can find that gives any type of help and still having this issue. But I keep getting this page.

[image: 404 error]

I am at a loss and not sure what else to do. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: so the issue is you get a 404 when you try to hit a development server over a VPN? please add info to your question about where the server is in relation to the user, both working and not, and how the VPN is involved in the users connection.

Comment: I will add to the post but this is just from my desktop, I connect to a VPN and connect to the site. We don't want the user to have to login to a specific server but just go to their browser and get to the site. So yes they use VPN to access our server to get to their site.

Comment: when it runs successfully, what is the url? does it contain localhost? you mentioned HTTPS; is the certificate on the server for a name that matches the DNS name of the website? do you have bindings for HTTP also, or just HTTPS?